# SELECT Array elements using Cosmos SQL query

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

Need to select array elements as row element.

Cosmos Documents JSON

1.

```
{
  "CountyId": 1
  "CountyCode": "Abbeville",
  "Cities": [
    { "CityId": 1, "CityName": "Arborville" }
  ]
}
```

2.

```
{
  "CountyId": 2
  "CountyCode": "Adair",
  "Cities": [
    { "CityId": 2, "CityName": "Ballard" },
    { "CityId": 3, "CityName": "Brashear" },
  ]
}
```

And the result that I need would like this.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected vs actual output, etc. As for a place to start: have you looked at doing a self-join (described in the Cosmos DB documentation)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am new to the Cosmos DB so was not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT c.CountyId, c.CountyCode, d.CityId, d.CityName FROM c
Join d in c.Cities
```

This produces the following output:

```
[
    {
        "CountyId": 1,
        "CountyCode": "Abbeville",
        "CityId": 1,
        "CityName": "Arborville"
    },
    {
        "CountyId": 2,
        "CountyCode": "Adair",
        "CityId": 2,
        "CityName": "Ballard"
    },
    {
        "CountyId": 2,
        "CountyCode": "Adair",
        "CityId": 3,
        "CityName": "Brashear"
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: that is what I was looking for, Thanks!